# Excel VBA: Detect error messages given by other application that was run using RunBatch

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I am calling a batch file form Excel-VBA script:

```
strCmdLine = "C:\temp\RunReporter.bat"
lngTaskID = Shell(strCmdLine, vbNormalFocus)
Call RunBatch(lngTaskID)
```

The batch file, in turn, triggers another application (some vendor). This application, at times, gives error messages (dialogue box).
It is necessary for someone to click "ok", so that the application closes, and then the handle comes back to VBA.

I wish to create a script that would detect the error messages and "click" on "ok, so that the VBA script continues to do the job.

Comment: Does the vendor application have a COM interface?

Comment: First I would look whether the vendor application has a silent mode in which the error messages will not appear.

Comment: Thanks for this @AxelRichter. I tried, and the answer is no. But it was a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I developed an application (executable) using AutoIt. The application runs in infinite loop, looking for error messages, and if found, closes the windows.

```
'some code
'shell the AutoIT application. 
'more code
'kill the shell AutoIt application
```